# regular expression converter (from PHP to JavaScript)

Tags: php, javascript, regex

This is the PHP regular expression I would like to convert into a JavaScript regular expression:

```
/(?<!\..|\...|\....)([\?\!\.]+)\s(?!.\.|..\.|...\.)/u
```

Are there tools to do such a conversion?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1131918/777982

Comment: There is no such thing as a "PHP regular expression" or a "JavaScript regular expression".

Comment: Hum. Well the above regular expression works with PhP but not with JavaScript. What's the problem?

Comment: There are, unfortunately, some slight differences between JavaScript's regexp engine and PHP's regexp engine. But true, regular expression "should" be universal between languages.

Comment: There's no negative lookbehind in Javascript's regex, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Randomblue, Javascript has no lookbehinds, you can partly simulate that behavior with a capturing group tho. What exactly do you want to do with this? Could help porting it if you give us some more info on what you want to do and sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?<!stuff goes here)` is a negative lookbehind which isn't supported by JavaScript's regex implementation. There are [some ways](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) to mimic it, but it does not work properly for all cases - yours looks like one of those to me.

If you want to keep using this specific regex, but from JavaScript, you could consider simply passing the string to PHP using Ajax, which would then run the regex on it.