# Converting Javascript Regex to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I know this question has been asked about a dozen times, but this one is not technically a dupe (check the others if you like) ;)

Basically, I have a Javascript regex that checks email addresses which I use for front-end validation, and I use CodeIgniter to double check on the back end, in case the validation on the front end fails to run properly (browser issues, for instance.) It's QUITE a long regular expression, and I have no idea where to begin converting it by hand.

**I'm pretty much looking for a tool that converts JS regexes to PHP regexes** - I haven't found one in any of the answers to similar questions (of course, it's possible that such a tool doesn't exist.) Okay, I lied - [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131918/converting-php-regexs-to-javascript-or-what-are-the-differences) suggested a tool that costs $39.95, but I really don't want to spend that much to convert a single expression (and no, there isn't a free trial as suggested by the answer to the aforementioned question.)

**Here's the Javascript expression**, [graciously provided by aSeptik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-validate-e-mail-address-regex):

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i
```

And the one used by CodeIgniter, which I don't want to use because it doesn't follow the same rules (disallows some valid addresses):

```
/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix
```

**I want to use the same rules set by the Javascript regex in PHP**.

Having this sort of inconsistency where my front-end code is saying that the email address is okay, and then Codeigniter says it isn't, is of course the behavior I'm trying to fix in my application.

Thanks for any and all tips! :D

Comment: @LarryBattle It could be, but the CodeIgniter file using it is a `.php` file, and the full line is this: `return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $address)) ? FALSE : TRUE;`

Comment: Try this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514810/php-email-validation-question

Comment: There is a tool that does exactly that: [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) can convert regexes from/to nearly any relevant flavor.

Comment: @TimPietzcker right, but as mentioned in the question, RegexBuddy costs $40 and I can hardly justify spending that to convert one regex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this in a better-than-expected manner. I was unable to convert the Javascript regex that I wanted to use (even after purchasing RegexBuddy - it'll come in handy, but it was not able to produce a proper conversion), so I decided to go looking on the [Regex Validate Email Address](http://ask.altervista.org/demo/jquery-validate-e-mail-address-regex/) site to see if they had any recommendations anywhere for good regexes. That's when I found this:

"The expression with the best score is currently the one used by PHP's `filter_var()`":

```
/^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/iD
```

It matches with only 4/86 errors, while the Javascript one I was using matches with 8/86 errors, so the PHP one is a little more accurate. So, I extended the CodeIgniter `Form_validation` library to instead use `return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`.

...But does it work in Javascript?

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/i);
```

Zing! Works like a charm! Not only did I get the consistency I was looking for between front and back end validation, but I also got a more accurate regex in the process. Double win!

Thank you to all those who provided suggestions!

Comment: What do you mean by "it was not able to produce a proper conversion?" Did you import it using the command `Paste from a JavaScript // Operator` and choose `PHP (preg)` on the Use tab with the `If/else branch whether the regex matches (part of) a string` option?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Maybe I didn't do it correctly - I pasted it in the top and used the dropdown `JavaScript`, and then in the bottom portion selected the `Use` tab, and finally language `PHP (preg)` with `If/else branch whether the regex matches (part of) a string`. Perhaps I should have used the `Paste from JavaScript // Operator`. The result, when I placed it in PHP, did not throw any errors, but nothing matched; everything came back as false.

Answer (score 4):

There are some differences between regex engines in Javascript and PHP. Please check [Comparison of regular-expression engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines)
 article for theoretical and [Difference between PHP regex and JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9072234/935073) answer for practical information.

Most of the time, you can use Javascript regex patterns in PHP with small modifications. As a fundamental difference, PHP regex is defined as a string (or in a string) like this:

```
preg_match('/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/',$telephone);
```

Javascript regex is not, it's defined in its own way:

```
var ptr = new RegExp(/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/);
// or
var ptr = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
```

You can give it a try by running the regex on PHP. As a recommendation, do not replace it in Codeigniter files, you can simply extend or replace native library. You can check [Creating Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) out for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error when placing the JS regex into a `preg_match`: `Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 44`

Comment: so modifying may be necassary sometimes :) look this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538293/php-regular-expression-pcre-does-not-support-l-l-n-p

Comment: Also, `/\\/` in JS will be `'/\\\\/'` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Today there is exists the site https://regex101.com/ where you can transform one JS regex to PHP or some another languages.